# ASP.Net Form, but date some columns, but not all

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have a form with the properties below.  When a request is submitted, it can show the details, which is good, however, when I edit the data, I want to only allow 3 items to be edited (to show if it is in progress and such), however, when I do not include the other items, it resets them all to "null".  I would like it to retain the original values.  I am not sure if I need to use a separate model for this, or if I can set the values to match what was already there: see below

Properties:

```
 public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Preparer { get; set; }
    public string Reviewer { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Eligible { get; set; }
    public string RiseDescription { get; set; }
    public int BudgetHours { get; set; }
    public int ActualHours { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime TocompleteDate { get; set; }
    public string Drive { get; set; }
    public string Completed { get; set; }
```

What I want to be edited:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Edit">

        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ActualHours"></label>
            <select class="form-select" name="ActualHours" id="ActualHours">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Completed"></label>
            <select class="form-select" name="Completed" id="Completed">
                <option value="not started">Not Started</option>
                <option value="in progress">In Progress</option>
                <option value="completed">completed</option>
                
            </select>
        </div>

       

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="RiseDescription" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="RiseDescription" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="RiseDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

I tried setting the other value like this, but it returned the code string:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="Name" value=`@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Name) id="Name" asp-for="Name" />
```

Comment: In the other html elements used to display the values of your model do you set anywhere the initial value?

Comment: I do, they are strings

Comment: That’s what I tried doing above, is to have a hidden input and set the value to what is in the database, but it’s setting it to the actual code

Comment: Do not set the value, it should be done automatically for you reading the actual value from the model passed from the controller (or code behind) to the view

Comment: Use `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.yourattribute)` inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.  I needed to use

```
<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" />
```

Instead of

```
 <input type="hidden" name="Name" value=`@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Name) id="Name" asp-for="Name" />
```